# Distinguish the existence of two separate strings

Tags: string, assembly, arm64

I have an assembly source file, named: helloworld.s:

```
.global _start            
_start: mov X0, #1    
    ldr X1, =helloworld 
    mov X2, #13     
    mov X8, #64   
    svc 0       
    mov     X0, #0      
    mov     X8, #93     
    svc     0           
.data
helloworld:   .ascii  "Hello nice warm World"
              .ascii  "Hello nice warm World2"
```

I created an executable file:

```
/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/as -o helloworld.o helloworld.s
/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld -o helloworld helloworld.o
```

and then, created an  objdump output of the executable file:

```
/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/objdump  -s -D    helloworld > objdum_output_helloworld.txt
```

This gives:

```
helloworld:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Contents of section .text:
...
 4000b0 200080d2 e1000058 a20180d2 080880d2   ......X........
 4000c0 010000d4 000080d2 a80b80d2 010000d4  ................
 4000d0 d8004100 00000000                    ..A.....        
...

Contents of section .data:
...
 4100d8 48656c6c 6f206e69 63652077 61726d20  Hello nice warm 
 4100e8 576f726c 6448656c 6c6f206e 69636520  WorldHello nice 
 4100f8 7761726d 20576f72 6c6432             warm World2     
...

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000004000b0 <_start>:

...
  4000b0:   d2800020    mov x0, #0x1                    // #1
  4000b4:   580000e1    ldr x1, 4000d0 <_start+0x20>
  4000b8:   d28001a2    mov x2, #0xd                    // #13
  4000bc:   d2800808    mov x8, #0x40                   // #64
  4000c0:   d4000001    svc #0x0
  4000c4:   d2800000    mov x0, #0x0                    // #0
  4000c8:   d2800ba8    mov x8, #0x5d                   // #93
  4000cc:   d4000001    svc #0x0
  4000d0:   004100d8    .inst   0x004100d8 ; undefined
  4000d4:   00000000    .inst   0x00000000 ; undefined
...

Disassembly of section .data:


00000000004100d8 <helloworld>:

...
  4100d8:   6c6c6548    ldnp    d8, d25, [x10, #-320]
  4100dc:   696e206f    ldpsw   x15, x8, [x3, #-144]
  4100e0:   77206563    .inst   0x77206563 ; undefined
  4100e4:   206d7261    .inst   0x206d7261 ; undefined
  4100e8:   6c726f57    ldnp    d23, d27, [x26, #-224]
  4100ec:   6c654864    ldnp    d4, d18, [x3, #-432]
  4100f0:   6e206f6c    umin    v12.16b, v27.16b, v0.16b
  4100f4:   20656369    .inst   0x20656369 ; undefined
  4100f8:   6d726177    ldp d23, d24, [x11, #-224]
  4100fc:   726f5720    .inst   0x726f5720 ; undefined
  410100:   Address 0x0000000000410100 is out of bounds.
```

The question:

How can I see from the objdump output only,  the existence of two separate strings:

```
"Hello nice warm World"
```

and

```
"Hello nice warm World2"  ?
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you are missing, you can already see them in the `.data` section.  Note that you should use `-d` instead of `-D` to not disassemble data as code.

Comment: Are you asking how you can tell that they are separate strings, rather than a single long string?  You cannot, that distinction doesn't exist in the memory contents.  You get exactly the same output from the assembler as if you had written `.ascii "Hello nice warm WorldHello nice warm World2"`.

Comment: thanks for replying.

I didn’t understand the meaning of “that distinction doesn't exist in the memory contents”.
And, since the machine does know to distinct between them (right? It would print only the first string, "Hello nice warm World" ??)  ,  how can I know this too, only from the executable and this objdump output?

Comment: The data is just bytes in memory.  The `write` system call takes a pointer to the first byte to be output, and a count of bytes.  The code will only output the first 13 bytes,  `Hello nice wa`, because you passed the value 13 as the count of bytes (`mov X2, #13`).  If you want to find out from the executable what part of that data is to be output, you have to look at the code that actually does the system call and deduce the register contents.  In this program you can see the `mov x2, #0xd` in the disassembly so it is easy.

Comment: But none of this has anything to do with the fact that you wrote the two messages as separate lines in your assembly source file.  That is irrelevant to the behavior of the program.  You could have combined them into one and the contents of memory would be exactly the same, and the program would still only print the first 13 characters if that was still the value you loaded into `x2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nate for your detailed answers.
Now, things are better understood!